# How to fix MySQL and PHP in WAMP not inserting data?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I’m using WAMP as my php server, I’m using PHP-AdminPage for my databse (usin MySql), Everything is working, my database is connected . except for when I want to display the data, rows are created but they’re EMPTY! even tho I didn’t leave them empty. I don’t understand, I’m so confused.

PHP Code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','');

//check connection
if ($conn-> connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Database Connected successfully";

//choose db
mysqli_select_db($conn,"catcafe");

//insert query
$sql="INSERT INTO customer(FName,LName,Email,PhNum,Time) VALUES('$_POST[firstname]',
'$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[Mobile]','$_Post[Time]')";

if($conn->query($sql) === true) {
    echo "New record created";
}
else{
    echo "Error, check values".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
}


mysqli_close($conn);
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

```
//insert query
$sql="INSERT INTO customer(FName,LName,Email,PhNum,Time) VALUES('$_POST[firstname]',
'$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[Mobile]','$_Post[Time]')";
```

MySQL keeps telling me that the error is here! but I dont know what it is, the columns have the exact same name as the ones in the database.

MY FORM /HTML CODE:

```
<form action="InsertReservation.php">
        <label for="fname">First Name  </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." style="width:600px; font-size: 30px;">
        <br>
        <label for="lname">Last Name  </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.."style="width:600px; font-size: 30px;">
        <br>
        <label for="Email">Email  </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Your Email is.."style="width:600px; font-size: 30px;">
        <br>
        <label for="Mobile">Mobile Number  </label><br>
        <input type="text" id="Mobile" name="Mobile" placeholder="Your Mobile Number is.." style="width:600px; font-size: 30px;">
        <br>
        <label for="Time">Time  </label><br>
        <input type="time" id="Time" name="Time" min="8:00"  required style="width:600px; font-size: 30px;">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="alert ('Thank you. Your Reservation Is Confirmed!')"> 
  <button type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="alert ('Reset is complete')"> Reset </button> <br>
      </form>
```

MySQL Code

```
SELECT * FROM `customer` ORDER BY `customer`.`FName` ASC
```

I want it to insert the data, but it keeps inserting empty data.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: You should learn to use prepared statements instead of substituting variables, to protect against SQL-injection.

Comment: @Renad To properly identify issue we need exact error message, table schema, dump of $_POST,

Comment: Try using the format: VALUES ('" . $_POST['firstname'] . "',
'" . $_POST['lastname'] . "','"  . $_POST['Email'] . "','" . $_POST['Mobile'] . "','" . $_POST['Time'] . "')"

Answer (score 1):

1. Validate your input data all the time.
2. Use prepared statments for user input
3. `Time` is a mysql reserved word so use backticks `` around it.

   ```
   $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');

   //check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   }
   echo "Database Connected successfully";

   //choose db
   mysqli_select_db($conn, "catcafe");

   //insert query
   $sql = "INSERT INTO customer(FName,LName,Email,PhNum,`Time`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";

   $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['Email'], $_POST['Mobile'], $_POST['Time']);

   if ($stmt->execute()) {
       echo "New record created";
   } else {
       echo "Error, check values " . $stmt->error;
   }


   mysqli_close($conn);
   ?>
   ```

Comment: This doesnt work as well!

 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bin_param() 
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::bin_param() i

Comment: I tried it again and it says : Error, check values Column 'FName' cannot be null   , even tho it is not null and I inserted data

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile How to do so?

Answer (score -1):

Hello Please use this code on a single file it's working fine.
Thanks

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');

    //check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Database Connected successfully";

    //choose db
    mysqli_select_db($conn, "catcafe");
    if($conn){
    //insert query

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Submit'){

     $sql = "INSERT INTO customer(FName,LName,Email,PhNum,Time) 
                VALUES('".$_POST['firstname']."','".$_POST['lastname']."','".$_POST['Email']."','".$_POST['Mobile']."','".$_POST['Time']."')";

        if($conn->query($sql) === true) {
            echo "New record created";
        }
        else{
            echo "Error, check values".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
        }
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    }

    <form method="post">
            <label for="fname">First Name  </label><br>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name.." style="width:600px; font-size: 30px;">
            <br>
            <label for="lname">Last Name  </label><br>
            <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.."style="width:600px; font-size: 30px;">
            <br>
            <label for="Email">Email  </label><br>
            <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Your Email is.."style="width:600px; font-size: 30px;">
            <br>
            <label for="Mobile">Mobile Number  </label><br>
            <input type="text" id="Mobile" name="Mobile" placeholder="Your Mobile Number is.." style="width:600px; font-size: 30px;">
            <br>
            <label for="Time">Time  </label><br>
            <input type="time" id="Time" name="Time" min="8:00" style="width:600px; font-size: 30px;">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="alert ('Thank you. Your Reservation Is Confirmed!')"> 
      <button type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="alert ('Reset is complete')"> Reset </button> <br>
          </form>
```

Comment: for some reason this also shows error that the database connection is failed, and doesnt insert data at all.

Comment: please use your right credentials to connect to the database. Also, provide me what error you are getting. @Renad